# Fast, searchable dict storage for Python

Tags: python, sqlite, data-storage

Current I use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (w/ [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)) to store about 5000 dict objects. Each dict object corresponds to an entry in PyPI with keys - (name, version, summary .. sometimes 'description' can be as big as the project documentation).

Writing these entries (from JSON) back to the disk (SQLite format) takes several seconds, and it feels slow.

Writing is done as frequent as once a day, but reading/searching for a particular entry based on a key (usually name or description) is done very often.

Just like apt-get.

Is there a storage library for use with Python that will suit my needs better than SQLite?

Comment: Why do you recreate the database from JSON every day? What does your insert code look like? If you are inserting a lot of data you might want to avoid the ORM layer of SQLAlchemy and use insert expressions: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html#insert-expressions

Answer (score 2):

Did you put indices on name and description?  Searching on 5000 indexed entries should be essentially instantaneous (of course ORMs will make your life much harder, as they usually do [even relatively good ones such as SQLAlchemy, but try "raw sqlite" and it absolutely should fly).

Writing just the updated entries (again with real SQL) should also be basically instantaneous -- ideally a single update statement should do it, but even a thousand should be no real problem, just make sure to turn off autocommit at the start of the loop (and if you want turn it back again later).

Comment: Actually, it is writing those 5000 entries that are slow. And, I essentially I have to write them all, say, every day. Think of "apt-get update" with an updated package index ready to be downloaded.

Comment: @srid, can you give the detailed CREATE TABLE statements? Looks like that must be peculiar indeed -- in my experiments it takes orders of magnitude longer to get info from pypi via xmlrpclib than it does to update it in sqlite (of course you only update in SQLite what's changed: why ever should you rewrite UNchanged entries?!).

Comment: there's a comment in the sqlite documentation that indicates that by default every individual `INSERT` is a transaction, taking minimally 2 disk rotations to complete (write and verify). If you wrap the whole works in a `BEGIN..COMMIT` block, you avoid that and get much faster throughput - http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html & http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html

Comment: @warren, excellent point -- autocommit _may_ well imply substantial slowdown (I normally disable it first-thing for other reasons anyway, but it's true that performance is one more reason to keep it disabled;-).

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill for your application, but you ought to check out schema-free/document-oriented databases. Personally I'm a fan of [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/). Basically, rather than store records as rows in a table, something like couchdb stores key-value pairs, and then (in the case of couchdb) you write views in javascript to cull the data you need. These databases are usually easier to scale than relational databases, and in your case may be much faster, since you dont have to hammer your data into a shape that will fit into a relational database. On the other hand, it means that there is another service running.

Comment: Yes, couchdb is an overkill for an essentially standalone command-line application. :-)

Comment: Whilst CouchDB is not my favourite datastore, I don't feel it's overkill - it seems to be a preferred option for self-contained or embedded systems (e.g. http://www.couchone.com/android )

Comment: Mongodb, on the other hand, has C-compiled JSON extensions and a very high speed by-default non-transactional datastore. But it very much prefers to be running a separate process as as special user, so has rather more setup overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Given the approximate number of objects stated (around 5,000), SQLite is probably not the problem behind speed. It's the intermediary measures; for example JSON or possibly non-optimal use of SQLAlChemy.

Try this out (fairly fast even for million objects):
y_serial.py module :: warehouse Python objects with SQLite

"Serialization + persistance :: in a few lines of code, compress and annotate Python objects into SQLite; then later retrieve them chronologically by keywords without any SQL. Most useful "standard" module for a database to store schema-less data."

http://yserial.sourceforge.net

The yserial search on your keys is done using the regular expression ("regex") code on the SQLite side, not Python, so there's another substantial speed improvement.

Let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving a very similar problem for myself right now, using [Nucular](http://nucular.sourceforge.net/index.html), which might suit your needs. It's a file-system based storage and seems very fast indeed. (It comes with an example app that [indexes the whole python source tree](http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/cgi-bin/nucularRepo.cgi/file/7675e470b95b/test/pythonIndexTest.py)) It's concurrent-safe, requires no external libraries and is pure python. It searches rapidly and has powerful fulltext search, indexing and so on - kind of a specialised, in-process, native python-dict store after the manner of the trendy Couchdb and mongodb, but much lighter.

It does have limitations, though - it can't store or query on nested dictionaries, so not every JSON type can be stored in it. Moreover, although its text searching is powerful, its numerical queries are weak and unindexed. Nonetheless, it may be precisely what you are after.